# How I can remove the Windows 7 professional from my PC with Windows 7 Ultimate installed?  

Tags: windows-7

I have two OS, first Windows 7 ultimate and second is Windows 7 professional.

Previously I only have Windows 7 ultimate, then I installed Windows 7 professional, to compare between both Windows.

Windows 7 professional it doesn't have some of the features on Windows 7 ultimate.

How I can remove the Windows 7 professional from my PC.?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking about deleting the boot manager when you just want to delete one of
your Windows 7 installations? Deleting the boot manager will leave you unable to access
either of your Win7's. Open Disk Management while booted into Win 7 Ultimate, find the
partition (Windows "drive") that contains your Win 7 Pro, right click on it, and choose
"format".